# Can't Load URL - facebook login on the app

Tags: facebook-login, appdomain, appsettings

I am trying to implement fb login on my game https://ski-jumps.pl. 
I prepared the application (settings below) and the script here: https://ski-jumps.pl/facebook.php

Unfortunately when I try to log in this app, a message is displayed: "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

What am I doing wrong? Some ideas?

[application settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHNCL.jpg)

Comment: The exact value of the redirect_uri parameter as used in the login dialog call must be in your Valid OAuth Redirect URIs setting ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, struggled for hours.  I fixed it by providing following url in the ***Valid OAuth Redirect URIs*** of the Facebook Login product

https://mysubdomain.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook

Regard the *signin-facebook*, which isn't something I provide.  I found this is the url of the Facebook error page.